# Why am I getting "'return' outside of function'" on this Django View?

Tags: python, django, view

This code, produces an error 'return outside of function'. All the other views in this file (views.py) are class based view (createview etc), but this view (the one I wrote from scratch) is throwing an error?

```
class Submit(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        submit_form = SubmitItemForm(data=request.POST)
        set_form = SubmitSetForm()

        if submit_form.is_valid():
            item = submit_form.save()
            item.save()

        elif set_form.is_valid():
            set = set_form.save()
            set.save()

    else:
        print(set_form.errors)

    submit_form = SubmitItemForm()
    set_form = SubmitSetForm()

    return render(request, 'curate/item_form.html',
                            {'submit_form':submit_form,
                             'set_form': set_form })
```

Comment: you have a class. you have a return statement just hanging in the open. If this is the complete code, the return statement does not have a function around it.

Comment: Main question: Why do you have this code in a class definitition?

Comment: Oh man. Dumb. I just got off food poisoning meds.... time to take a day off I think..

Comment: The way you are writing your view is like a view function, not a class based view. just change `class` to `def` and it must work.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how **django** class base view work.

try to make pure **function base view** or **class base view**

```
def Submit(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        submit_form = SubmitItemForm(data=request.POST)
        set_form = SubmitSetForm()

        if submit_form.is_valid():
            item = submit_form.save()
            item.save()

        elif set_form.is_valid():
            set = set_form.save()
            set.save()

    else:
        print(set_form.errors)

    submit_form = SubmitItemForm()
    set_form = SubmitSetForm()

    return render(request, 'curate/item_form.html',
                            {'submit_form':submit_form,
                             'set_form': set_form })
```

and refer this for [CBV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you are using a class instead of a function. Since only functions can return, this does not work. If you really want to use it in a class, you can do something like this:

```py
class Submit_in_a_class:
    def class_submit(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            submit_form = SubmitItemForm(data=request.POST)
            set_form = SubmitSetForm()

            if submit_form.is_valid():
                item = submit_form.save()
                item.save()

            elif set_form.is_valid():
                set = set_form.save()
                set.save()

        else:
            print(set_form.errors)

        submit_form = SubmitItemForm()
        set_form = SubmitSetForm()

        return render(request, 'curate/item_form.html',
                                {'submit_form':submit_form,
                                 'set_form': set_form })
def Submit(request):
    Submit_in_a_class.class_submit(request)
```

However it is probably best to do this:

```py
def Submit(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        submit_form = SubmitItemForm(data=request.POST)
        set_form = SubmitSetForm()

        if submit_form.is_valid():
            item = submit_form.save()
            item.save()

        elif set_form.is_valid():
            set = set_form.save()
            set.save()

    else:
        print(set_form.errors)

    submit_form = SubmitItemForm()
    set_form = SubmitSetForm()

    return render(request, 'curate/item_form.html',
                            {'submit_form':submit_form,
                             'set_form': set_form })
```

Cheers!